# customDismissAction not working for remote notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I'm attempting to tracking push notification opens and dismissals with a custom analytics system on iOS and I have been unable to get any `UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier` responses to come through.

My code that registers with the notification center:

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] integerValue] >= 10){
    UNNotificationCategory* generalCategory = [UNNotificationCategory
                                               categoryWithIdentifier:@"GENERAL"
                                               actions:@[]
                                               intentIdentifiers:@[]
                                               options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionCustomDismissAction];

    // Register the notification categories.
    UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center setNotificationCategories:[NSSet setWithObjects:generalCategory, nil]];
    [center setDelegate:self];
};
```

When I send my push notification, I set the category to GENERAL. When I receive the notification and swipe right to dismiss it, I don't receive any delegate callbacks.

Does customDismissAction only work for local notifications?

Comment: Did you have any luck? Don't `customDismissAction` suppose that you should pass some action into initializer?

Comment: can you show us your payload structure? is `category` written under the `aps` key?

Comment: Are you calling [`setNotificationCategories‍‍‍`](https://www.google.com/search?q=setNotificationCategories&oq=setNotificationCategories&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0j69i60j0l2.417j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) once across your entire app? When ever you call it, it **replaces** previous categories. So upon registration you should have ALL your categories ready

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same issue. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW1) mentions that this needs to be part of your APS payload for the remote notification. I had to read over it quite a bit before I found/picked up on it. Make sure to add whatever category you want to the push payload and have it match when registering the dismiss action. So if you used the example "GENERAL", the payload should include that category

```
"aps" : {
  "category" : "GENERAL",
  "alert" : {
     "body" : "Some message",
  },
  etc...
}
```